# app not save in android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I build react-native app, after launching the app in android emulator by command

```
react-native run-android
```

I see the app open in emulator and it works fine but after close the app i don't see the icon in the emulator and even I don't find it when I search it.

the configuration in android folder :
MainApplication.java

```
    package com.glassify;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import community.revteltech.nfc.NfcManagerPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n.RNI18nPackage;
import com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera.RCTCameraPackage;
import io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchPackage;
import io.branch.referral.Branch;
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;


// import facebook sdk
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
      return mCallbackManager;
    }
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new RNDeviceInfo(),
            new NfcManagerPackage(),
            // new FBSDKPackage(),
            new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
            new RNI18nPackage(),
            new RCTCameraPackage(),
            new RNBranchPackage(),
            new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    // SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

  }
}
```

but when i run it in ios it save the icon and I see it after I close the app.

Comment: Are you using Expo?

Comment: no. I don't use Expo.

Comment: Can you update your original post to include the emulator settings?

Comment: Nexus 5x API 23,that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to appear in the emulator you need to run it from the IDE, not the command line. Go into Android Studio, select you device and click run. It should appear then.

Here is some extra info about Android Emulators https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxOTmjKHQ1wIV7pPtCh1Rdw7REAAYASAAEgJmTPD_BwE

Comment: Hi @Adir Zoari. Does my answer above solve your issue or is it still an issue? As a newbie on stack overflow i would love the extra reputation points :)